# Nav Bar Dropdown overlapping under content

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with my CSS nav bar. The issue is that the child links are under the div below the nav bar, obstructing the link. I'm not sure how to make the nav bar display OVER the rest of the content rather than under.

You can see the issue here: http://nellyswritingroom.tumblr.com/ by scrolling over link 1.

```
nav {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul:after {
    content:"";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
}

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top:0;
}
```

If anyone could offer any insight into how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: add z-index:10; to the element that needs to sit on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a z-index so nav looks like

```
nav {
    z-index: 999;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

this will keep the nav bar ontop of everything. Also it does not need to be 999 but this is the max value so if you add more layers your nav will stay on top